# How to add ImageSpan at end of lines in multiline text

Tags: android, string, textview, spannablestring

I want to add a span at the end of each line in multiline strings. I tried to draw just a char, but nothing appeared at end of lines. But when `ImageSpan` is set, it can increase line height, but still no image at the line.

```java
private void addSpansAtEnd() {
    String s = "First line\nSecond line\Third line\n";
    SpannableStringBuilder e = new SpannableStringBuilder(s);
    int stop = start + count;
    for (int start = -1;
        (start = s.indexOf("\n", start)) > -1 && start < stop;
        ++start) {
            e.setSpan(
                    /*new ImageSpan(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_line),*/
                    new NewLineSpan(),
                    start,
                    start + 1,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}

/* Trying to replace \\n with other character. */
private class NewLineSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
    @Override
    public int getSize(
            Paint paint,
            CharSequence text,
            int start,
            int end,
            Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(
            Canvas canvas,
            CharSequence text,
            int start,
            int end,
            float x,
            int top,
            int y,
            int bottom,
            Paint paint) {
        paint.setColor(0xFF666666);
        canvas.drawText("o", x, y, paint);
    }
}
```

How do I draw at end of lines?

Comment: I'm guessing you want an image like this: ↲  (Which BTW you can use a character like I did instead of an image) So the question is, do you want it just on your "hard" CR/LFs i.e. where you put "\n" in your example (which should be ¶ instead of ↲), or also on the "soft" CR/LFs i.e. where the `TextView` decided to wrap your multi-line text?  Because handling the soft CR/LFs adds an extra layer of challenge.

Comment: ↲ is \u21B5, ¶ is \u00B6, unfortunately \u21B5 is not in Roboto font, so I suppose that's why you need an image.

Comment: I just want to show lineendings and do not break original string. Image or char, but only with spans.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a span on a newline seems sort of weird.  A newline goes across two lines but doesn't have any width.  I think you might have more luck if you add a space before the newline then put the span around the space:

```
for (int start = -1;
    (start = s.indexOf("\n", start)) > -1 && start < stop;
    start += 2) { // increment by 2 to skip the displaced newline
        e.insert(start, " ");  // insert a space for the span
        e.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_line),
                start,
                start + 1,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        stop++;  // because a space was added
}
```